# разбиение страницы на 3 части с помощью Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

гуру бутстрапа подскажите можно ли в bootstrap разбить страницу следующим образом:

```
<div class = 'screen'>
    <nav class = 'menu'></nav>
    <div class = 'info'>
        <div class = 'left'></div>
        <div class = 'right'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

где

```
.screen {
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh; 
}

.menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

.info {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}

.left {
    width: 250px; // тут возможные варианты
}

.right {
    width: calc(100% - 250px);
}
```

т.е. страница занимает весь экран (!), сверху во всю ширину экрана и заданной высотой меню, под меню слева одна панель заданной ширины, справа вторая панель.

Когда использовал классы bootstrap, то пришлось для высоты панелей сформировать свой стиль

Можно ли обойтись только бутстрапными?

Извиняюсь - только начал изучать данную библиотеку

P.S.

в идеале конечно хотелось бы, чтобы при уменьшении ширины браузера левая панель схлопывалась бы и при нажатии на неё вертикально разворачивалась (как меню).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Бутстрап - это конструктор из готовых решений, он ограничен. Каждый из вас может построить «Свой Бутстрап». Если вы используйте Бутстрап, то вам никто не мешает комбинировать его базу со своими решениями.

Comment: т.е. это не ошибка, когда я за основу беру бутстрап и дальше начинаю добавлять свои классы, выкидывать бутстраповские, комбинировать, мешать и т.д.?

Comment: @Zhihar Это решение.То что вы можете добавлять/комбинировать сами, - это очень хорошо. Не обязательно ломать бутстрап. К примеру можно в html тэг добавит свой класс после бутстрап класса, например <тэг class="бутсрап ваш". Тогда в том же файле css от Бутстрап можно ниже писать: .бутстрап.ваш { нужные свойства

Comment: @Zhihar Дам рекомендацию. Не ломайте файл CSS от Бутстрап (типа стирание/перепись оригинальных строчек). Есть такая поговорка: Ломать - не строить. Просто в этом же файле добавляйте/комбинируйте своё волшебство.